# Is there any easy way to check backward compatibility for powershell scripts?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0

I have written a powershell script and it should work both in version 1 and version 2.

Can more than one powershell versions co-exist in a single machine ? Or should i have powershell versions in separate machine ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the answer is yes and no.

Technically, on PowerShell 2.0 system, you can access PowerShell version 1.0 using

> -version 1

parameter of powershell.exe

Similarly, on PowerShell 3.0 system, you can acccess PowerShell verison 2.0 using

> -version 2

You cannot have both installed seperately on the same machine. PowerShell itself provides a way to go to the earlier version.